# Efficient way to merge two array of objects in javascript based on similarities?

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, server, backend

So I have two array of objects:

```
var arr1 = [{id:1, name:John }{id:2, name:Adam }]

var arr2 = [{id:1, address:NY, number: 200}, {id:2, address:LA, number: 300}]
```

and the expected result is:

```
var newArr = [{id:1, name:John, address:NY, number: 200 }, { id:2, name:Adam, address:LA, number: 300}]
```

This is just two examples out of thousands of data, I have tried mapping through two arrays and inserting them manually however this would always result in a timeout since I think looping is quite heavy on the backend server. Is there an efficient way to do such an operation or a lightweight solution in packages like lodash to achieve this?

Comment: Are you using `id` to identify which elements to group together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you're using native module, lodash and other packages will also loop over the values internally.

Assuming that you're using `id` to group the elements together, this is probably what you want

```js
function mergeArrays(array1, array2) {
  const groups = {};

  for (const array of [array1, array2]) {
    for (const elem of array) {
      if (!groups[elem.id]) {
        groups[elem.id] = {};
      }

      Object.assign(groups[elem.id], elem);
    }
  }

  return Object.values(groups);
}

var arr1 = [{id:1, name:'John' }, {id:2, name:'Adam' }];
var arr2 = [{id:1, address:'NY', number: 200}, {id:2, address:'LA', number: 300}]

console.log(mergeArrays(arr1, arr2));
```

Answer (score 0):

why use Librarie if you can achieve with core `javascript`

```js
var a1 = [{id:1, name:'John' },{id:2, name:'Adam' }, {id: 3, name: 'mohit'}]

var a2 = [{id:1, address:'NY', number: 200}, {id:2, address:'LA', number: 300}, {id: 4, name:'dj', value: 'pj'}, {id: 5}]

let a3 = [...a1, ...a2].reduce((acc, x) => {
    acc[x.id] = Object.assign(acc[x.id] || {}, x);
    return acc;
}, {});
console.log('your need', Object.values(a3))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear how you want to combine elements, by shared index in the two arrays or by shared `id` values.  Either way, you can easily write simple utility functions that make this trivial.

#### With Shared Indices

First if it's a matter of shared indices, we could do something like this:

```js
const zipWith = (fn) => (xs, ys) => xs .map ((x, i) => fn (x, ys [i]))

const combine = zipWith ((x, y) => ({...x, ...y}))

const arr1 = [{id:1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Adam'}], arr2 = [{id:1, address: 'NY', number: 200}, {id:2, address: 'LA', number: 300}]

console .log (combine (arr1, arr2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We write a generic helper function `zipWith` -- which you will also find in many utility libraries -- that accepts a combining function and returns a function that takes two lists and returns the result of running that function against the two elements at each index.  (If the arrays are not the same length, there might be odd behavior.)

Then we write `combine` atop `zipWith`, by just passing it a function that naively merges the two objects.  We could pass it `Object .assign`, but that will modify the first element it received, and that's not a style I enjoy.

#### Grouped by id

If we want to work with shared `ids`, we would do this a bit differently.  Rather than scanning for the element in the second list with an id matching our current one from the first list, with algorithmic time of `O (m * n)`, where `m` and `n` are the lengths of the two arrays, we can fold into an object with the `id` as a key and values of arrays containing all the elements from our arrays with that `id`.  That is something most utility libraries call `groupBy`, and will change it to `O (m + n)`. We can write a `mergeBy` function on top of that, which will first do the `groupBy` with a function supplied, and then merge all the elements in each of the values of the `groupBy` result into single elements.  It looks like this:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x, _, __, k = fn (x)) => ((a [k] = a [k] || []), (a[k] .push (x)), a), {})

const mergeBy = (fn) => (...xss) => 
  Object .values (groupBy (fn) (xss .flat ())) .map (xs => Object .assign ({}, ...xs))

const combine = mergeBy (x => x .id)

const arr1 = [{id:1, name: 'John'}, {id:2, name: 'Adam'}], arr2 = [{id:1, address: 'NY', number: 200}, {id:2, address: 'LA', number: 300}]

console .log (combine (arr1, arr2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Here `mergeBy` is a second utility function layered atop `groupBy`.  `combine` just passes it an id-extraction function.  This time we're easily able to use `Object .assign`, since we're calling it with our elements, we can just prepend an empty object to them first.<sup>1</sup>

There is additional flexibility in this version.  It automatically handles multiple values with the same `id`.  And it allows you to pass arbitrarily many arrays.  So you can use it with a single array that has duplicate `id`s or with many arrays.

#### Lesson

The important point here is that either version of this is simple to write, when you keep handy a collection of useful utility functions.  `groupBy` and `zipWith` are available to me immediately, and I might well add `mergeBy`, which also seems useful.  A library of these either your own, or a more battle-tested public library, is a great tool to have in your coding toolbox.

---

<sup><sub>1. Again, no Objects were mutated in the making of this output.</sub></sup>